# how to resize image before inserting into database using php?

Tags: php

This is my page

```
<html>
<span>Attached File :</span>
<input type="file" name="fileAttach" id="fileAttach" value="" />
</html>
```

in the database page i have like this

```
<?php
$file =$_FILES['fileAttach']['name'];
$ext = substr($file, strrpos($file, '.') + 1);
$filename=date('YmdHis').".".$ext;
$imageName=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileAttach']['tmp_name'],"photo/".$filename);

$strQry="insert into table(photo) values('".$filename."')";
?>
```

Before inserting this photo into database ,i want to resize that photo in a particular width and height.how can i resize and insert the resize image in db.

Comment: use google you will see several examples

Comment: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

Comment: thanks  Shehzad Bilal

Comment: All the cool kids use Imagine these days: https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resizing images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295712/resizing-images)