# whats a good php gd aspect ratio crop within a width/height limit?

Tags: php, gd

if i want to crop an image within the limits of 900px by 1000px what is a good formula to use to crop an image by its aspect ratio within the given limits and preferably using a percentage crop so that the image doesn't get distorted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999250/php-gd-cropping-and-resizing-images

Answer (score 0):

Check out this php class. http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php

It can scale an image by width, height, or percentage. And you can resize an image to a width, height, or both.