# Image uploading concept in PHP

Tags: php

how to take image from one folder and rename and re-size the images and move to another folder? 
I need to get image from one folder and rename and re-size the same image and move into another folder using php

Comment: Are you stuck at some specific point or do you just want teh codez for all that?

Comment: what  have tried so far...can u post ur code

Comment: i not have code...?so can u help me...?

Answer (score 2):

You will most likely be using gd for resizing the images.
Here is a pretty crappy, but hopefully useful code sample. In this case, $originalName is the name given in the $_FILES array's tmp_name position. I am resizing to a width of 1200 in this case, with the height adapting according to such width. You might (and most likely will) not desire this behavior. This is just some ugly code I used in some courses I taught about 3 years ago, I don't have the newer samples in this computer so you will have to get used to the idea :)

$newDir is where the file will be located. by calling imagejpeg or imagepng and passing the filename as second argument, it means to the function that you wish to save the image in that location.

```
if ($type == 'image/jpeg') {
    $original = imagecreatefromjpeg($originalName);
}
else {
    $original = imagecreatefrompng($originalName);
}
$width = imagesx($original);
$height = imagesy($original);
//prepare for creation of image with width of 1000
$new_height = floor($height * (1200 / $width));
// create the 1200 width image
$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor(1200, $new_height);
// copy and resize old image into new image
imagecopyresized($tmp_img, $original, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 1200, $new_height, $width, $height);
//create a random and unique name to identify (here it isn't that random ;)

$newDir = '/this/is/some/directory/and/filename.';
if ($type == 'image/jpeg') {
    imagejpeg($tmp_img, $newDir."jpg");
}
else {
    imagepng($tmp_img, $newDir."png");
}
```

Comment: how to get image from main folder? we had two folders i need to take image from main folder and resize it save it in another folder...so in this code where i can get image from main folder?

Comment: oh, so you're not uploading a new image. If there's only one image, then just make the $originalName be the full path to that image (you don't need any other changes in that case). If you want several, you can retrieve a list of files in said folder using a DirectoryIterator http://php.net/manual/es/class.directoryiterator.php

Comment: if the response seems as an answer to your question, it would be great if you could accept is as answer (clicking on the left of the up and down arrows, the checkmark (turns green).

Comment: sorry..i got a small problem with this script..?i gave full path of the image as $originalName.but it's not workin as well.

Answer (score 1):

Many file system functions are already built-in with PHP (e.g. `rename`), and you'll find most of what you need to resize images by using the GD library [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php).

Comment: i know to re-size image...how to get image from one folder and re size it?

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries available in PHP for image resize.
Here are some useful links you may like.

1. http://www.fliquidstudios.com/2009/05/07/resizing-images-in-php-with-gd-and-imagick/
2. http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php
3. [PHP/GD - Cropping and Resizing Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999250/php-gd-cropping-and-resizing-images)
4. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

Use imagick library to resize; it's good.

Answer (score 0):

Use imagick http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would write a PE using a diffent language (one that you might be best used to) to adjust anything of the given image then just feel free to phpexec it to do all the steps you mentioned, you can sit relax and wait for the end result. HHAHAHHA :-)