# Crop an image but leave the default size

Tags: php, image

I have images which have lots of space in top, bottom and left. How can I just delete that space and get a new smaller jpeg image?

Comment: I have lots of images and want to do it with PHP.

Comment: Can you please define "space"? does that mean just a solid color?  White or black?  How many do you have?

Comment: I have many. It's just color, background noise and etc. Does it matter?

Comment: You already said "many".  If many means 10, you should just do it with photoshop, if many means 1,000,000, then a smart php solution would save a ton of time .... so how many?

Comment: Let's just say I want to have a solution to do it with PHP... :)

Comment: Do you need php to autodetect these crop lines?  If so, "random" noise would be very difficult.  If it were a constant "black" or another other color, you could do it

Comment: Can you give a link to a sample photo you want "cleaned"?

Comment: Use the GD library. See here for a similar Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999250/php-gd-cropping-and-resizing-images

Comment: [ImageMagick?](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: you can't. Not accurately at least. JPEG compression will leave artifacts that result in the image not being cropped properly.

However, if you're insistent, you could crop the image with a tolerance.

First, you'd need to pick the "empty" colour. This in itself is a challenge, but usually the top-left pixel `(0,0)` works okay.

Once you have your empty colour, scan across the top rows until you find a pixel that is not the same colour (or within a small margin, to accomodate JPEG artifacts). Save the number of the row on which you find a non-empty colour.

Repeat the process from the bottom of the image.

Then, do the same thing for the columns from the left and right, but only scan between the top and bottom rows you already found (to avoid redundantly checking the corners).

Finally, use the dimensions to copy out the image to a smaller canvas, and save.

Comment: I agree that this is how I would do it, but I would never use this, too many variables. The notion of "tolerance" is VERY difficult to define.  The OP said "noise", too me that means wildly different colors which would destroy the concept of a tolerance.  If by noise, the OP meant it was a solid color that varied very slightly based on the jpeg artifacts, then you *might* have a shot