# Image module in nodejs with resize/crop/concat

Tags: javascript, image, node.js, gd

I need a suggestion about nodejs module. I have 3 images I should crop/resize and concat them in one single image like this:

[image]

Can you suggest me node module to use, that can fit my needs.

I reviewed

- https://github.com/aheckmann/gm: seems to have what I need (crop/resize), but as I read you can't concat few images like this.
- https://github.com/taggon/node-gd: I can find any documentation or information about this one

Comment: Try the newer version with a lot more documentation: https://github.com/y-a-v-a/node-gd

Answer (score 0):

The Acheckmann/gm link was better when i saw both but then keeping your issue in mind i found out something related to the node-gd.

[PHP/GD - Cropping and Resizing Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999250/php-gd-cropping-and-resizing-images).

Indeed it lacks sufficient doc but i guess you will have your work done with this. Good luck

Comment: Can I concat 3 images in one with gd?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion:

use gm to crop/resize,
then draw it in canvas together by

https://www.npmjs.com/packages/canvas